# Mysql groupBy similar products based on relationship if there is any

Tags: mysql, group-by, junction-table

How can I groupBy product_id a query on `transactions` but I need the products with options to be shown separately.

For example in the table `transactions` if I have:

```
ProductID Quantity Price

    1       1       10
    1       1       10
    1       1       15 (in transaction_options this has option green(price 2,5),yellow(price 2,5))
    1       1       15 (in transaction_options this has option red(price 2,5),blue(price 2,5))
```

I want the result to be:

```
 ProductID Quantity Price
    1       2       10
    1       1       15 (this has option red(price 2,5),blue(price 2,5))
    1       1       15 (this has option green(price 2,5),yellow(price 2,5))
```

The problem is that they all have the same product_id, and the price can be the same but for different options.

This are the tables structure:

`products` with `id,name,price`

`options` with `id,name,price`

`transactions` with `id,product_id,quantity,price`

`transaction_options` with `id,transaction_id,option_id` (association table between `transactions` and `options`

In `transactions` I insert the `price` calculated based on option (if there are any) :

`product.price+[option.price] = transaction.price`

Comment: So a product can have a base price and 4 option prices? and the option prices are always the same? and you will only have a quantity of 1 in transactions? I think you need to add a bit more detail including sample data from product and options as a starter.

Comment: The options can be unlimited and the option prices are not the same. The options prices in my example are the same to show that I cannot `groupBy` price because there could be different options.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible since a combination of base price * quantity could result in the same value as base price + option price * quantity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from (select col1, col2 from myTable where myOptions is not null) union all (select col1, count(col2) as col2 from myTable where myOptions is null group by col1);
```